# Xpath-like package for Python to find keys on all level in lists and dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, xpath, package

Given is a data structure which has the key `TEXT` in arbitrary positions in the structure like this example:

```
{'info': [
    {'TEXT': 'SUBINLIST'},
          {'duda': {
              'TEXT': 'SUBSUB',
              'walter': 'jaja'}}
          {'hey': [
              {'jess': 'morning'},
              {'TEXT': 'DEEPEST'}
          ]}  
    ],
 'TEXT': 'TOPLEVEL'}
```

I want to find the values of the `TEXT` keys. Is there a XPath-like package for Python where I can define an appropriate path expression so that I get for the example the following result returned:

```
['SUBINLIST', 'SUBSUB', 'DEEPEST', 'TOPLEVEL']
```

*Note:* I do *not* want to find the keys through a recursive Python function, but via an call to a package/library/module (which obviously will do that internally as well).

I tried [`jsonpath-rw`](https://github.com/kennknowles/python-jsonpath-rw), but could not come up with an expression which finds the values in arbitrarily nested dicts *and* lists.

Comment: There's [jmsepath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jmespath). And [objectpath](http://objectpath.org/).

Comment: Ok, and how does the expression look like to get **all** `TEXT` values through all sub dicts and sub lists in jmsepath or objectpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`jsonpath`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath/) as below:

```
import jsonpath

my_dict = {'info': [{'TEXT': 'SUBINLIST'},{'duda': {'TEXT': 'SUBSUB','walter': 'jaja'}}, {'hey': [{'jess': 'morning'}, {'TEXT': DEEPEST'}]}], 'TEXT': 'TOPLEVEL'}
print(jsonpath.jsonpath(my_dict, "$..TEXT"))
```

*Output:*

```
['TOPLEVEL', 'SUBINLIST', 'SUBSUB', 'DEEPEST']
```

Comment: Cool! XPATH expression "$..TEXT" via `jsonpath` - that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: BTW and for completeness: The library `jsonpath-rw` works as well with your XPATH expression.